# How can I find the software/service that is reading from the Bluetooth device

Tags: usb, virtualbox, bluetooth

I have a VM that’s using my Intel NUC Bluetooth.  But I don’t remember how I set this VM up.  If it weren’t for the fact that I know a program is getting information from `/opt/bluetooth/c0:B6:F9:8D:A6:75` I wouldn’t know that Bluetooth was even working in the first place.

Additionally `dmesg | grep blue -i` returns the following, so I know it’s configured somehow:

```
[   25.470189] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[   25.470221] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   25.470229] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   25.470234] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   25.470241] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   25.613169] Bluetooth: hci0: Firmware revision 0.1 build 197 week 12 2021
[  801.994803] Bluetooth: hci0: advertising data len corrected
```

I’m trying to setup a new VM that will also use Bluetooth.  Yes, I’m turning off the “working” VM so it won’t interfere with the new one.  But on my new VM I don’t have a `/opt/bluetooth` directory, probably because I don’t have something installed/configured correctly.

What can I do on the *working* VM to determine what I might need to install on the new one?  I’ve tried running various BT utilities, like `hcitool` but none of them are installed.  Something has to be reading this.  How can I find out what it is so I can setup the new VM with it?

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is likely to be found in `/opt/bluetooth/`. I would expect a readme.txt and/or install.txt in that directory with a link to where the original source is stored and how you install this software.

`/opt/bluetooth` means you installed 3rd party software from source. At least... if you followed the (not so official :) ) guidelines.

This tends to come with 2 methods:

1. you copy an executable from `/opt/bluetooth` to a directory on the system, then add this to a crontab (`crontab -l` as user or as root or `more /etc/crontab`)

or

2. in `/opt/bluetooth` there is a file ending on `.service` that you start. I would assume anyone would call it `bluetooth.service` and if that is the case this would tell you if it is active:

   systemctl status bluetooth.service